# Erro "Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Alguma ajuda com o erro abaixo?

> Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Html5DataList-DESKTOP-P3666CV' ou uma de suas dependências. A definição do manifesto do assembly localizado não corresponde à referência do assembly.

LOG:

> === Informações sobre estado pré-associação ===
>   LOG: DisplayName = Html5DataList-DESKTOP-P3666CV
>    (Partial)
>
> AVI: informação de associação parcial foi fornecida para um assembly:
>
> AVI: Nome do Assembly: Html5DataList-DESKTOP-P3666CV | ID do Domínio: 2
>
> AVI: uma associação parcial ocorre quando somente parte do nome de exibição do assembly é fornecida.
>
> AVI: isso pode fazer com que o associador carregue um assembly incorreto.
>
> AVI: é recomendável fornecer uma identidade textual totalmente especificada para o assembly,
>
> AVI: que consiste no nome simples, na versão, na cultura e no token de chave pública.
>
> AVI: Consulte o white paper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 para obter mais informações e soluções comuns para o problema.
>
> LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/OneDrive/VisualStudio2017/006-Html5DataList_FDFEDFontes/Html5DataList/
>
> LOG: PrivatePath inicial = D:\OneDrive\VisualStudio2017\006-Html5DataList_FDFEDFontes\Html5DataList\bin
>   Chamando assembly: (Unknown).
>
> LOG: esta associação começa no contexto de carregamento default.
>
> LOG: usando arquivo de configuração de aplicativo: D:\OneDrive\VisualStudio2017\006-Html5DataList_FDFEDFontes\Html5DataList\web.config
>
> LOG: usando arquivo de configuração de host: C:\Users\itaro\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
>
> LOG: usando arquivo de configuração da máquina de C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>
> LOG: a política não está sendo aplicada para referência neste momento (particular, personalizado, parcial ou associação de assembly baseada em local).
>
> LOG: tentando download de nova URL file:///C:/Users/itaro/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/d73f5939/aadb14e5/Html5DataList-DESKTOP-P3666CV.DLL.
>
> LOG: tentando download de nova URL file:///C:/Users/itaro/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/d73f5939/aadb14e5/Html5DataList-DESKTOP-P3666CV/Html5DataList-DESKTOP-P3666CV.DLL.
>
> LOG: tentando download de nova URL file:///D:/OneDrive/VisualStudio2017/006-Html5DataList_FDFEDFontes/Html5DataList/bin/Html5DataList-DESKTOP-P3666CV.DLL.
>
> AVI: a comparação de nome de assembly resultou na incompatibilidade: NAME
>
> ERR: falha ao concluir configuração do assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing encerrado.

**Rastreamento de pilha**

> [FileLoadException: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Html5DataList-DESKTOP-P3666CV' ou uma de suas dependências. A definição do manifesto do assembly localizado não corresponde à referência do assembly. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
>
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
>
> System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
>
> System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Html5DataList-DESKTOP-P3666CV' ou uma de suas dependências. A definição do manifesto do assembly localizado não corresponde à referência do assembly. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>
> System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
>    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +92
>
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
>
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
>
> System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +549
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Html5DataList-DESKTOP-P3666CV' ou uma de suas dependências. A definição do manifesto do assembly localizado não corresponde à referência do assembly. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10084960
>
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
>
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

Comment: Aonde acontece isso? como acontece?

Comment: Assim que executo o botão verde pra executar o site.

Comment: Este artigo é top, vai te ajudar com certeza. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 6):

Sei que a pergunta é antiga, mas apenas para referência, vou deixar aqui o link para a resposta em inglês com as possíveis soluções em português.

Isso tem a ver com uma referencia em 64 apontando para 32 bits ou vice versa.

1-Então caso o seu projeto seja 64 bits a possível solução é ir até Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects e marcar a caixa "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express".

2-No Gerenciador do IIS ir até Application Pools -> DefaultAppPool -> Advanced Settings -> Marcar "Enable 32-bit applications" como true

Pergunta original:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745612/infamous-assembly-binding-error